# MySQL issue. Take only rows with more than 1 hour delta delay and do it recursively

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I am writing code in SQL Workbench. I have a table with time-based updates of information for the user. The table looks like this:

Title: client_val_time

```
| id  | cl_id | time_captured       | value
| 100 | 1     | 2019-08-01 15:35:00 | 3.1
| 101 | 1     | 2019-08-01 15:36:00 | 3.2
| 102 | 1     | 2019-08-01 15:37:00 | 3.234
| 103 | 1     | 2019-08-01 15:45:00 | 3.5
| 104 | 1     | 2019-08-01 16:40:00 | 5
| 105 | 1     | 2019-08-01 17:00:00 | 5.1
| 107 | 1     | 2019-08-01 17:45:00 | 5.534
| 108 | 1     | 2019-08-01 18:50:00 | 3.21
```

The problem is that I do not need all observations due to their noisy nature and also some memory reasons do not allow that. The ideal timedelta for me would be 1+ hours.

So, as a result, I want to see the table like that:

```
| id  | cl_id | time_captured       | value
| 100 | 1     | 2019-08-01 15:35:00 | 3.1
| 103 | 1     | 2019-08-01 15:45:00 | 3.5
| 107 | 1     | 2019-08-01 17:45:00 | 5.534
| 108 | 1     | 2019-08-01 18:50:00 | 3.21
```

I tried to figure out an approach for this, but there is no way I can solve this.
Maybe there are other ways to solve this problem, I do not need all the observations, because value column does not vary much and, moreover, I cannot load the full dataset to filter it with other instruments.
I would be very thankful for any advice.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What are you actually using here? I've removed the tags, please tag only the correct RDBMS. (SQL Workbench *implies* MySQL, not SQL Server) Also, what have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Larnu, I tried other approaches for solving the problem, but with this one, I do not know how to start writing code. It is rather complicated

Comment: "other approaches"? I don't see any attempts in your question. If you've tried something please show us that attempt; it's very hard for us to tell you where you went wrong when we can't see what it was you did.

Comment: I mean I tried the other stuff to load less data, like taking only small periods of time and taking first k rows for each cl_id. I did not write any valuable code for this question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with the approximate solution which best fit my needs. As soon as I needed only 1-hour delay, I only take the first observation for each unique hour. It does not guarantee the 1+ hour delay due to the occasion when first 'time' for some hour is close to the next one.

```
select w_0.id, w_0.cl_id, 
       w_0.time_captured,
       w_0.value
from client_val_time w_0 inner join
(
    select  w.cl_id, 
            year(time_captured) as year_time,
            month(time_captured) as month_time,
            day(time_captured) as day_time,
            hour(time_captured) as hour_time,
            min(w.id) as min_id
    from client_val_time w
    group by w.cl_id, year_time, month_time, day_time, hour_time
) loc_val on loc_val.min_id=w_0.id;
```